# Unity how do I play an intro only the first time the player starts the game?

Tags: unity, c#, animation

I have an intro animation scene in my game that I want to play the first time the player hits play from the main menu. How do I do this?

Comment: Persisting data when the game is closed is the whole purpose of the PlayerPrefs class.

Comment: @Philipp so its essentially an autosave for certain information?

Comment: Yes, you could think of it like that. Although you can also save it manually in case your game tends to crash a lot.

Comment: @Philipp Yeah once my game size gets big again and causes lag I will work on a save feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never done this, and I'm not familiar with Unity, but here's how I'd do it.

You could use the [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) to implement that feature. When your player hits "Play", start first by checking if they have a preference saved. If they have, skip the intro, if not, save the preference and play the intro.

```
if ( PlayerPrefs.HasKey("HasSeenIntro")
{
    // skip to what shows up after they've been show the intro animation
}
else
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HasSeenIntro", 1);
    // play the intro
}
```

I think until you have a more complex mechanism of saving the game, this should be enough.